# Variety of issues testing Android Webview using Appium

Tags: java, junit, android-webview, appium, selendroid

I have a hybrid app that is primarily just a webview. Here is the code for the basic test:

```
  @BeforeClass
  public static void setupAppium() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.5.3");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "AppiumTesterDevice");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "/work/builds/unify/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.company.unify");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "AdministerActivity");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
  }

  @Test
  public void CompanyUrlTest() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys(companyserverUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/android.widget.Button[2]")).click();
  }

  @Test
  public void SimpleTest() {
    driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.company.unify");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".localPickerList")));
    driver.findElementByCssSelector(".localePickerList").click();
    driver.findElementByCssSelector(".SPANISH_PR").click();
  }
```

The first test works fine because it's just operating on normal android app, no webview. So its just changing the URL in a text field and pressing a button to take us to that URL in the webview.

The second test is where there are problems, and the problems change depending on android version and chromedriver version. I've done tons of googling and can only conclude there is an endless series of bugs with appium/selendroid/chromedriver.

I downloaded the latest Chromedriver from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads. And in my appium settings, I have set the chromedriver path to point at this. In my Android 6.0 I get this error with this version of ChromeDriver:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Can't stop process; it's not currently running (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 224 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'company-me-m', ip: '192.168.1.154', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.4', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=/work/builds/unify/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk, appPackage=com.company.unify, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=emulator-5554, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=emulator-5554, appActivity=AdministerActivity, desired={app=/work/builds/unify/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk, appPackage=com.comany.unify, appActivity=AdministerActivity, appium-version=1.5.3, platformVersion=6.0, automationName=Appium, platformName=Android, deviceName=AppiumTesterDevice}, appium-version=1.5.3, platformVersion=6.0, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, automationName=Appium, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
Session ID: bc7100bd-2498-47d2-b0f2-3b29602c8e0d

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.context(AppiumDriver.java:557)
    at com.comapny.UnifyAppiumJunit.BasicTest.SimpleTest(BasicTest.java:57)
```

Without this version of Chromedriver set in appium options, I get a different error (I don't however, know what chromedriver executable its using when I'm not specifying it). Here is that error:

```
Jan 27, 2017 3:02:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.cssSelector: .localPickerList)
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
```

It seems like it's not even letting my webview load in both cases. While the app is loading the webview, the code runs anyway, which seems bad. Why isn't the Wait seemingly doing anything? Does this even matter?

Finally, if I use my Android 5.1.1 emulator, I get this error:

```
WebDriverException thrown by findElement org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any ideas? I've been banging my head against google all day over this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With new UIautomator you don't need to switch your driver to webview. It has built in capabilities to identify the elements inside webView.

Please update your Android SDK once.

Elements inside WebView will be visible in UIAutomator for Android Version 6.0+ versions. However, once you automate the script for Android 6.0+ device, you can use the same script for Android version below 6.0.

And also you can see the elements inside webView on Android 6.0+ devices using UIAutomator.

For more information refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679673/android-6-x-webview-undefined-when-switching-context/41719409#41719409)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's amazing in all my googling I did not find any indication that Android 6.0 Webviews could be automated using Appium. It's still weird I can't do it the other way, but oh well. I got my tests running using this method.

Comment: Follow up question: Is there a nice way to get web elements aside from their xpath or content-desc? If I was using the webview context, I could use css selectors (if it wasn't super buggy), which is nice because I can set special selectors for test cases and name them whatever i want. Can I do anything like this using your method?

Comment: @Slims You can always use xpath for finding elements. Xpath is the best method. I always use it. And Yes! You can use resource-id,id,name,text,content-desc or index for constructing xpath.